# Cleaning up stale .class files using Apache Ant

Tags: java, ant

How do I clean up stale `.class` files out of `${workdir}` given set of existing `.java` files in `${srcdir}`? By stale I mean `.class` files that were generated from now removed `.java` files. I have tried coming up with something using Ant mappers and filesets etc. but I failed. Removing all `.class` files older than their respective source `.java` files would be acceptable, too.

Comment: Interesting question, but can I ask "why bother?"  Is there any harm in unreferenced class files hanging around until the next time you run your "clean" target (even if that's never)?

Comment: What's wrong with nuking ${workdir} and let javac create fresh .class files every time?

Comment: @Mark Peters: As I understand it, they will get bundled into a `.jar` file if not removed. Blowing away all `.class` files each time you change something is not acceptable with the size of source I have here.

Comment: Ah, ok.  I see where you're coming from.  Typically when I create ant scripts I use a separate target for local compilation than for packaging/bundling.  When I run a packaging target I run my clean target first and then run compilation, whereas for just local compilation (to test & debug) I don't clean.

Comment: @wilx, What's the "size of source" you have there that's unacceptable to blow away all .class files?

Comment: @Cem: I think the point is that *rebuilding* it takes a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure there's an ant task to kill .classes older than the .java...

[Depend](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/depend.html) sounds close, and may actually do what you want, but this isn't its intended purpose.  Given developmentalinsanity's answer however, this may be the only thing that will Actually Work.

Comment: This looks very promising! I have been staring into the docs the whole day today but I have not seen the <depend> task. I will test it tomorrow first thing.

Comment: Unfortunately, `<depend>` apparently does not remove `.class` files generated from now non-existing `.java` source files.

Comment: Sounds like a feature request.  Until then you may be forced to go with `ant clean`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is determining whether a class file without an obviously corresponding source file is really stale.

Try this in a single file (A.java)

```
public class A{}
class B{}
```

This will result in both A.class and B.class. So, B.class would seem stale because of the missing java file. You'd probably get similar issues with any inner classes.

Safest bet if you want to make sure there's no old class files lying around would be just to delete them all.

Comment: I think that the nested classes case can still be solved by finding all A$*.class files for A.java, unless I am mistaken. I don't think that this source code has that many .java source files with multiple classes in them. Imperfect solution would still be better than nothing I have now. :)

Comment: @wilx To be honest then, I'd just stick will deleting all class files. Especially if the code-base is relatively small, the time to fully recompile shouldn't be that big a problem.

Answer (score 1):

As it’s just not possible to detect what’s stale and what’s not, most builds have a *clean* target (that’s also part of *cleanbuild*). The *clean* target, just removes all files from you’re *build* directory. This directory normally is unversioned (svn:ignore).

Not all files in you’re build will be the result of the compiler, for example .property files, these files can be stored in an alternative directory that will be copies in to the *build* directory. For example in a web application build you can store those files in /web/WEB-INF/classes and let Ant copy them into the build directory.

Comment: I have already taken care of other files using the combination of <copy> and <sync> tasks.

Comment: Sounds like he's trying to speed up his build in a more general case and has a lot of 'flux' in his java classes.  Unusual, but not inconceivable.