# Ant <depend>: remove class files for missing source files

Tags: java, ant, dependencies

The Ant [`<depend>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/depend.html) task works well enough for the most part, but if a source file is deleted or renamed then the associated class file isn't deleted.  How would I go about automatically deleting those class files as well?

Comment: There is not "depend" task in standard ANT, See: http://ant.apache.org/manual/tasklist.html. Could you provide an example?

Comment: I found a "depend" task on that page: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/depend.html

Answer (score 0):

Answer can be found at [Cleaning up stale .class files using Apache Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099845/cleaning-up-stale-class-files-using-apache-ant).
In few words, it is complicated for external build system like Ant to track all dependencies from Java classes to `.class` files.
So it's better to remove all `.class` files in scope of a cleanup step before the build.